# Android async loading images using Picasso in List adapter

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, bitmap, picasso

I have a list view in my Android app which uses `AppsAdapter`
for each row.This adapter tries to load an image from a given URL and cache it.
This is the code of the adapter 's image loading method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    View v;
    ViewHolder vh;
    v = buildView(convertView);
    vh = findViews(v);

    AppWithImage app = apps.get(position);

    setData(vh, app);
    return v;
}

private View buildView(View convertView) {
    View v;
    if (convertView != null) {
        v = convertView;
    } else {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate((listMode) ? R.layout.item_apps_list : R.layout.item_apps_grid, null);
    }
    return v;
}

private void setData(ViewHolder vh, AppWithImage app) {
    id = app.getId();
    vh.appTitle.setText(app.getName());
    vh.appRating.setRating((float) app.getRating());
    if (app.getIcon() != null) {
        vh.appIcon.setImage(app.getIcon());
    } else {
        vh.appIcon.setImage(noImageBitmap);
        if (app.getIcon_url() != null && !app.getIcon_url().equals("")) {
            loadBitmap(Constants.GET_IMAGE_ICON + app.getIcon_url());
        }
    }
    vh.appIcon.setHasShadow(!listMode);
    vh.id = app.getId();
}

Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // do something with the Bitmap
        onFileLoaded(id, bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
        Log.i("Bitmap", "Bitmap failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
        Log.i("Prepare", "Bitmap failed");
    }
};

public void loadBitmap(String url) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(target);
}
```

Since I'm not using an Image view I need to use a Target instance that handles the bitmap for me and makes its stuff. The problem is that the first time I run the app the `onPrepareLoad` method is always called from Picasso but nothing is returned from the URL and therefore I don't have images in my list.

Second time I run it it works fine. Even if I scroll the first time, android loads the images perfectly once they've finished the download.

I've been inspecting Picasso's source code and I've seen it enqueues an action to load the URL's bitmap when cache fails and I think this is potentially my problem, because when It loads the stream from the URL the adaptor and the Target instances are basically gone.

How can I solve this to be able to reach the `onBitmapLoaded` method?

Comment: picasso dose not load any image from your list when you open app for first time ? 
I think in first time picasso take long time until load images so in second time picasso may load images from cache-memory. 
you can use `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` indicator to knows how picasso load images